# Changing the contents of an overlay based on id pulled from database

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a page that has a list of companies pulled from a mysql db. Each company name is a link and when clicked an overlay comes up containing further details on that particular company.

Everything is working...my list is created, link pulls up the overlay, but as of now it only populates the info for the company that is the last record. I know I need to pass the record id to the jquery so that it pulls the record for the name clicked, but I am just not familiar enough with jquery to figure it out. I believe I need to pass it to a parameter, but need a nudge in the right direction. Below is my current code with just the basics, I have passed the unique id for each record via `mid="<?php echo $member->member_id; ?>">` in the link...I just need to pass that to the overlay.

```
<p>
<li><a href="#" class="modalInput" rel="#profile2" mid="<?php echo $member->member_id; ?>"><?php echo $member->company_name; ?></a>
</li>

</p>



<!-- Profile Overlay -->
<div class="modal2" id="profile2">


    <dl>
        <dt>Address:</dt>

        <dd><?php echo $member->address_city; ?>

        <dt>Phone Number:</dt>
        <dd><?php echo $member->phone; ?></dd>

    </dl>

    <!-- close button -->
    <p>
        <button class="close"> Close </button>
    </p>
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

var triggers = $(".modalInput").overlay({


    // mask tweaks
    mask: {
        color: '#ebecff',
        loadSpeed: 200,
        opacity: 0.9
    },

    closeOnClick: false
});


});

</script>
```

Comment: To get the value it will be $('.modalInput').attr('mid'), but you need to know which one is clicked. So it needs to be in a function like $('.modalInput').click(function(){ $(this).attr('mid') }); What plaguin are you using for the overlay?

Comment: I am brand new to jquery...followed tutorial here : http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/modal-dialog.html

Comment: Using this `<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Well because you are setting the inner HTML elements with server code, it will only ever display one record. You need to add an onclick listener for your .modalInput and in that make an AJAX call to a PHP script passing in the MID attribute for the selected modalInput. Then when the AJAX call returns, assign the output to the correct fields. You will need to look through jQuery docs to do this. You may need a bit more understanding of the technologies for a task of this level. Take a look here

http://api.jquery.com/click/ and
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you I haven't found the answer yet, but I am studying...lol...just didn't want you to think I didn't appreciate the help : )